# Valuation of Mortgage Backed floating notes

Tags: valuation, mbs

Does anybody have experience in valuation of mortgage backed floating notes? I have task to value the 4 different MBS floating notes. I know that it should be done through montecarlo, refinancing function should be created to consider the effects of prepayment. Need more exact and detailed advice on steps should be taken.

I am interested if it makes sense to go with short way. To treat the floaters as regular floaters and value them as regular floater, then adjust for the prepayment and credit risk.

any papers or advice from experienced professional are highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: more information needed. Provide details of the notes then maybe it makes it clearer what is necessary.

Comment: Are you valuing commercial or residential backed securities?

Comment: both commercial and residential